# Writing the results of this PHP script to a text file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I don't even know if this is possible, so feel free to shoot me down if it's a silly question, but I can't think of a way to do it.

This is my script which grabs data from the database and formats the results how I want them :

```
$users = get_users('user_login', 'display_name', 'ID');

echo 'users: [ ';
$n = count($users);
foreach ($users as $i => $user) {

echo '{ name: "'.$user->user_login.'"';
echo ' username: "'.$user->display_name.'"';
echo ' image: "'.$user->ID.'" }';
if (($i+1) != $n) echo ', ';
}
echo '] ';
```

Which basically spits out the following when run directly :

```
users: [ { name: "007bond" username: "James Bond" image: "830" }, { name: "4Tek" username: "4Tek" image: "787" } ]
```

But instead of running this script when I need it (which will be a lot) I'd like to write the results of this script to a text file.

Is this possible?

Comment: if you know fopen why dont  you use it?

Comment: Yes I know how to use fopen and fwrite but I can't figure out how to set the variable to write.

Comment: You really shouldn't manually create JSON. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You're already creating invalid JSON by leaving quotes off of the keys. You can test your JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: It's not valid JSON that i'm trying to create. That's the problem, the jQuery program that I am using this with doesn't accept JSON. This is a javascript array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fopen and fwrite

```
$users = get_users('user_login', 'display_name', 'ID');

$string= 'users: [ ';
$n = count($users);
foreach ($users as $i => $user) {

    $string.= '{ name: "'.$user->user_login.'"';
    $string.= ' username: "'.$user->display_name.'"';
    $string.= ' image: "'.$user->ID.'" }';
    if (($i+1) != $n) $string.= ', ';
}
$string.='] ';

$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $string);
```

Comment: Doh! of course, I need to concatenate the string... Thanks LTasty ;)

Comment: Dont forget to `echo $string` at the end if you still want to see the results

Answer (score 1):

You can use a several ways to write text to file.
1. Without php, just redirect script output to specific file like this:

```
# php yourfile.php > result.txt
```

And then you have a result in result.txt.

2. With php a possible way:

```
    $users = get_users('user_login', 'display_name', 'ID');

    $text = 'users: [ ';

    $n = count($users);
    foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
       $text .=  '{ name: "'.$user->user_login.'"';
       $text .= ' username: "'.$user->display_name.'"';
       $text .= ' image: "'.$user->ID.'" }';
       if (($i+1) != $n) $text .= ', ';
    }
    $text .= '] ';

    file_put_contents( 'result.txt', $text );
```

Comment: can you explain how I would use your solution? Sounds very interesting. Looks like it's a bash script command?

Comment: First approach based on common output redirecting in bash console. In the same way you can catch any output from any script to specific file. Just use a ">" sybmol after any command and you will catch standart output (for erros catching you need some more changes).

Comment: Yep that's what I figured. Thanks for that, I'm sure it will come in handy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too . just incase

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
foreach ($users as $i => $user) {

fwrite($fp, 'whatever');
}
fwrite($fp, 'anything');

fclose($fp);
```